# Insert plugin content before body end

Tags: plugins, php

How do I make plugin's content appear in a place I want? For example let's say I have a plugin that output's a paragraph:

```
echo "<p>foo<p>"
```

If I do this it will appear on a page outside the DOM. How to make it append for example just before the end of body using PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hook the [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) action to output markup before `</body>`:

```
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>foo</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```